# VLC blinking when playing video

Tags: 16.04, video, vlc

When I am playing VLC, it is blinking. Impossible to watch.

What can be done?

Can't find disabling acceleration options, recommended in other answer.

Comment: Have you tried a standalone compositor such as [compton](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/compton.1.html)?

Answer (score 5):

click tools --> preferences ---> video

first try changing output to opengl before disabling acceleration.

Comment: Blinking nevertheless, although somehow differently

Answer (score 5):

Changing video input(not output) to VA-API over DRM working for me

Comment: Precisely, in my case using VLC version 2.2.2; Click tools --> preferences ---> Input/Codecs --> Hardware accelerated decoding;  Setting to either "VA-API Decode via X11" or "VA-API Decode via DRM" instead of "Automatic" fixed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

select video output to X11 works.
for this  Go to Tools -> preferences -> Video -> Output(Drop-down menu) select X11 video output.
and it works

Answer (score 1):

this worked August-2018

tools > preferences > input/codecs >

hardware-accelerated decoding -- change from automatic to Disable

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem what fixed my problem was that i had the preload mkv's in the same directory option enabled in video/codec settings.

It would make it blink at first then crash vlc entirely. it had no problem preloading in a directory with 474gb worth of 500mb tv shows.

But on certain 12gb folder of mkv files that were a bit over 800mb it would crash.